# How to run cluster local registry?

Tags: ingress, images, docker-registry, cache

I want to set up a cluster local docker registry so that I can push/pull images very quickly without some of the policy restrictions of my corporate docker registry (for example, all images in that registry have to have certain labels set, something that `kaniko` cannot do for cached images).

The goal would be to serve as an image cache that could be used by both CI/CD build jobs, as well as for deployment to the cluster itself.

I have been able to set up a registry in the cluster, but I've run into a few issues:

- What should the FQDN be for the registry?

  - If I tag the images using internal cluster name (like `registry.<ns>.svc.cluster.local`), then how can I get `containerd` running on the cluster to deploy the images?
  - If create an ingress, and then tag the images using that FQDN I have to:

    1. Set up an ingress
    2. Secure the ingress so that only the servers in the cluster can access the ingress

If it matters, this is an on-prem cluster, where the servers are running containerd (no docker is installed)

What is the best way to go about doing this? I feel like there has to be an easy way, but I'm not seeing it